# How can i access the inner object values of an object in mvel?

Tags: java, reflection, mvel

Object obj=account;
here account object contains books as inner object. So how can i access those values in mvel.

I am new to MVEL. So can you please auggest me how to overcome the above issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MVEL` works on **OGNL**.

Let say `Account.Class` has `Books.class`

1.) Simple object , not a collection

**OGNL** - `account.books.bookName`

2.) Complex object, a collection (`Account.class` has collection of `Books.class`)

**OGNL** - `account.books[0].bookName`

or Take collection out and put one by one.

```
book.bookName
```

This is what can be explained simply, otherwise scope of your question is big and not much clear.

Comment: How can i make it dynamic.For example if i have an Object type then how to make MVEL expression dynamic? and i can know the the object at runtime only. So can you please explain it more clearly....

Comment: @RAJASHYAM `OGNL` cannot be dynamic unless you create using `Java Reflections`

Comment: So how can i use Java Reflections in MVEL.?

Comment: @RAJASHYAM pls post different questions after giving a try, otherwise scope becomes huge, question could be closed.